# How to show percentage and number in pie chart?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.1

I am working on pie chart to show my data. I can work fine with it just now to show only percentage. But what I wish to do is to show both percentage and number.

[image: The result I work on show as below]

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
        var data = [];
        @if(count($data) > 0)
          data = <?php echo json_encode($data)?>;
        @endif
        var options = {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: false,
                clickable: true
            },
            colors: ["#94BEE0", "#D9DD81", "#E67A77","#747ddd","#669aaa","#aa7765"],
            tooltip: true,
            tooltipOpts: {
                defaultTheme: false
            }
        };
        $.plot($("#pie-chart #pie-chartContainer"), data, options);
};
```

**My data result**

```
$total_amount = array_sum($interest_income);
    foreach($interest_income as $key => $inc){
        if($inc > 0){
            $per_value = ($inc * 100)/$total_amount;
            $data[] = [
                'label'=> $label[$key],
                'data'=> $per_value
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Flot pie charts show data value instead of percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673870/jquery-flot-pie-charts-show-data-value-instead-of-percentage)

Comment: I found that answer that may duplicate my question. But I can't understand the answer that why I decided to ask here again.

Comment: @TumLina That's why people need to explain their answer more. Lots of *"try this"* answers pop and and are not useful. Anyways what is in your `data`, you can do something similar depending on what `data` is.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - my data is the result of my calculate in my php function as above.

Comment: @TumLina agreed, the answer isn't great. I've tried to explain in my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP is generating percentages, but you'll need to change it to generate the raw numbers (Flot can work out the percentages automatically):

```
foreach($interest_income as $key => $inc){
    if($inc > 0){
        $data[] = [
            'label'=> $label[$key],
            'data'=> $inc
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, in your JavaScript, use a formatter for your labels like this:

```
formatter: function (label, series) {
    var labelName = label;
    var labelNumber = series.data[0][1];
    var labelPercent = series.percent;
    var labelContent = label + '<br/>' + labelNumber + ' (' + labelPercent + '%)';
    return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;">' + labelContent + '</div>';
},
```

You would include this in your options, like this:

```
var options = {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            label: {
                formatter: function (label, series) {
                    var labelName = label;
                    var labelNumber = series.data[0][1];
                    var labelPercent = series.percent;
                    var labelContent = label + '<br/>' + labelNumber + ' (' + labelPercent + '%)';
                    return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;">' + labelContent + '</div>';
                },
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: false,
        clickable: true
    },
    colors: ["#94BEE0", "#D9DD81", "#E67A77","#747ddd","#669aaa","#aa7765"],
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        defaultTheme: false
    }
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LvLfcdur/

Comment: OK, let's me try this first.

Comment: I have a question: where is the series.percent come from?

Comment: @TumLina it's automatically populated by the Pie Chart plugin for Flot.

Comment: Still I can't show my pie chart as your jsfiddle. I'm not sure it because of my data jsonencode or what.

var data = [];
            @if(count($data) > 0)
                data = <?php echo json_encode($data)?>;
            @endif

Comment: @TumLina I suggest using `console.log` to output the value of `data` to see what it contains.

Comment: @TumLina I've just spotted the problem, you do need a modification to your PHP. I'll include the changes in my answer.

Comment: I have reached my gold now. Thank you for your helping.